# Wrong content type / charset when creating a new message with MCOMessageBuilder with a plain/text attachment

Tags: swift, swift3, imap, attachment, mailcore2

I'm still trying to add custom headers to a message by copying it and adding the headers to the new message (see also my unanswered question [mailcore2: Adding a custom header to IMAP message doesn't work (newly written to the IMAP server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923637/mailcore2-adding-a-custom-header-to-imap-message-doesnt-work-newly-written-to)).

For messages with attachments, this works already. The attachments of the original message are copied to the new one including the (plain) text message, which is also an attachment. Great! :-)

Now I try to do the same for a message without any attachments. When I look at the source of the original message, the headers are:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Now I try to copy the message body as attachment with the following code (Swift 3):

```
let abstractMainPart: MCOAbstractPart = messageParser.mainPart()

if abstractMainPart.partType == MCOPartType.single {
    let attachment: MCOAttachment = abstractMainPart as! MCOAttachment
    messageBuilder.addAttachment(attachment)
}
```

Then I send the message with

```
let appendOp = self.imapSession.appendMessageOperation(withFolder: withFolder, messageData: messageBuilder.data(), flags: MCOMessageFlag(rawValue: 0), customFlags: ["$label1"])

appendOp?.start{ (err, createdUid) in
    log.debug("error from server \(err)")
    log.debug("created uid: \(createdUid)")
}
```

The problem is, that in the new message, the text is replaced by base64 encoded text. The headers say:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
[...many header lines...]
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

How can I prevent the conversion from plain ISO-8859-1 text to base64 encoded text?

Or alternatively: How can I get a plain text String without any flattening, removing whitespace, HTML rendering etc. out of the original message or the original attachment???